# Как поставить два загрузчика?

Tags: windows, macos, boot

Есть задача: установить на один диск windows, на второй hackintosh. При этом, оба должны запускаться без проблем. Копался в загрузчике clover, но не нашел инфы по запуску windows.
Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой и как-то решал ее?

Answer (score 0):

Поступить по аналогии с linux + windows: сначала устанавливаем мастдай, а затем, на другой раздел, линух. Линукс в своём загрузчике пропишет запуск винды. При загрузке компа будет вызываться, например, grub, где и будет осуществляться выбор нужной ОС. Почему рекомендую попробовать данный вариант: макось выходец из мира *nix - поэтому его загрузчик должен работать аналогично.